# React - Use async function for rendering in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, promise, jsx, firebase-storage, es6-promise

How can I use a promise function inside the return of a component, like this:

```
function MyComp () {
 return (
  <div>
   {getFirebasePromise(ref).then(url => return url)}
  </div>
 )
}
```

So the result would be:

```
<div>urlFromFirebase</div>
```

Do I have to use a `useState()` even though I have several promises in the same component?

Comment: You can't use a promise there, it might not exist yet on the first render

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useState` and `useEffect` to do that.

```
function MyComp () {
    [url, setUrl] = useState("");
    useEffect(()=>{
        getFirebasePromise(ref).then(url => setUrl(url));
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            {url}
        </div>
    )
}
```